# How to group and render smaller templates into one file using Twig

Tags: php, twig

I just started using Twig and have been reading up on it. I don't want to create a whole file for a small template such as:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ firstname }}</td>
    <td>{{ lastname }}</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to group my templates into one file and be able to render a specific snippet/template from the file. Obviously I could easily do this by using pure PHP but I want to keep my HTML separate from my PHP because it just looks a lot cleaner. I might look into saving the templates into a database but that just seems like a lot of work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i would stick to one template per file.

Comment: You could use [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html). But I would advise using separate files for seperate views and view partials.

Comment: @JimL I thought about using macros but you have to import the macro from within another template so I don't see how I could render a single macro. I may just go with the separate files and organize them in folders, or maybe just go with a template database.